# union of two vector layers gives only one layer attributes as output

Tags: python, pyqgis, vector-layer

layer1[image: layer1] layer2[image: layer2] Resultant union Layer[image: Resultant union layer]It is giving only one layer as output

I have used the following

```
val='layer1'
val2='layer2'
operation='qgis:union'

processing.runalg(operation,val,val2,'result.shp')
layerAdded = iface1.addVectorLayer(os.getcwd(),'result', "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layerAdded )
```

Comment: Try to equalize the layer's fields before utilizing union. I have done a similar thing but using 'qgs:mergevectorlayers', I suggest giving it a try if the problem persist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

processing.runandload(operation,val,val2, 'result.shp')

solved the problem,
loading it the way I have done above was giving incomplete attributes in the result layer